# Ejabberd server on AWS t2.micro instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, memory, central-processing-unit, ejabberd

I am just worried about the performance issues of running `Ejabberd`(XMPP) chat server on 1GB RAM and 1CPU core AWS t2.micro instance.

`Ejabberd` documentation says it can easily accept concurrent connections of 100K to 300k if the machine has 16GB of RAM and 4 CPU cores.

But I have only 1GB RAM and 1CPU. If I run `Ejabberd` chat server on this machine can it withstand at least 10000 connections? And how efficient is it to run a chat server on this machine(1GB,1CPU) for 10000 connections?

Answer (score 0):

That server is definitely too small to handle 10000 connections. You need a larger server for that kind of usage.